# Bitnami (XAMPP) Wordpress Multisite Installation Redirect Loop

Tags: wordpress, xampp, bitnami, multisite

Windows 7 64-bit local install of XAMPP.

Followed the instructions given by Wordpress to enable multisites, but a redirect loop keeps happening when trying to log into a newly created site.

Looked through answers on here, Wordpress SO, the wordpress forum, and other blog posts. No solutions have worked.

Wordpress Version: 4.1

Local URL: http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/

**wp-config.php**

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '127.0.0.1');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**htaccess**

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /wordpress/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

**httpd-app.conf**

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>






    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</Directory>

Include "C:/xampp/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

Comment: did you try removing all htaccess? you should start debugging, by removing your htaccess file and remove all rewrite rules

Comment: Unfortunately, removing my htaccess and all rewrite rules in httpd-app.conf didn't solve the issue, which makes me believe it is something in the wp-config. Any suggestions on how to further debug?

Comment: remove everything on that directory even wordpress. you should also avoid adding rewrite rules in `.conf` file, put all your redirect rules inside `.htacces`. First thing you need to do is to make that directory accessible, add simple php file and see if it will run properly